# How to create attribute based product in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I need to set product based upon their weight and dimension for a delivery system, so i have created sample 5 products each having different attribute based upon their w&d .Then each time when admin places order to a customer(adding to shopping cart) from those products based upon w&d. Now the problem i face how to change the Image and description of the product or order for each customer i have placed this image and description varies for every customer. Is there a way do it. I am open to any suggestion to achieve this can also use php and js if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have solved it yourself alraedy by saying "image and description varies for every customer", so it would make sense to add customer attributes that hold this information. You will have to modify stuff around in your .phtml files though to make this fully work.

Furthermore it would be good if you included what you have tried already.

Comment: I am little slow in magento so far i have configured on back end alone not gone through code section. Here the image and description is given by admin . can i give those image and description like configurable products or some popup to ask for image url and description when placing order to customer, if so where should i make those changes in magento.

Comment: If the image and description is different for each customer I wouldn't go this way. Else you could just do a configurable product as you said ;)

Comment: but the configurable products only have dropdown only ,i need a textbox where image url can be entered so that it can be configure while placing order in customer. I can manipulate image url in php but where should i do it ?

Comment: So basically you have a few products and for each order the customer has to be able to enter an image and description? (You running a T-shirt printing webshop?) This would mean that you have to foresee 2 fields per item in your order and save the information to the session/somewhere else somehow. After the order has been placed you could use one of the events of Magento to capture the information entered by the customer and insert it as a comment with the order.

Comment: here the admin places order for the customer and admin will also upload an image and description of the product order that placed for the specific customer then the product image and description of the product varies to every customer .the customer only login and pays the bill for the product added to order(shopping cart).

Comment: Then you could just create generic products (example: 1 tshirt with custom logo and description) and let the customer pay that?